# patching a function if that function is imported using the from statement

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I have a case similar to the following code where I am trying to patch a fucntion that is imported using the from statement:

```
from module1 import function1

def function2():
    function1_result = function1()
    return 2*function1_result
```

and then the testing code is:

```
from unittest import patch
def test_function2():
    func1_value = 5
    with patch("module1.function1", return_value=func1_value) as patched_func1:
        function2_value = function2()
    assert function2_value==2*func1_value
```

However the code runs but it doesn't use the patched function 1 and actually calls the function. However, if I change the import statement to just `import module1` then the test runs fine.

Comment: You should patch `module2.function1` where `module2` is wherever function2 is and where you have imported `function1` into, as in context of test code `function1` is accessed from that module, after the import.

Comment: I don't think this is the issue as when I change the import to just `import module1` then the test runs fine. (I have amended the question)

Comment: it will run fine then because after your change, inside the test code the function to patch is `module1.function1`, think about it in terms of where `function1` lives in your code, and what patch is replacing calls to. in the failing case you brought function` into the module2 namespace. so patching needs to replace calls to `module2.function1`. in the latter case module1 was imported and function1 is still referred to as module1.function1 so patching works fine

Comment: aaah yes I'm with you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) doc, the examples in the documentation are very clear.

`module1.py`:

```py
def function1():
    return 1
```

`module2.py`:

```py
from module1 import function1


def function2():
    function1_result = function1()
    return 2*function1_result
```

`test_module2.py`:

```py
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch
import unittest
from module2 import function2


class TestModule2(TestCase):
    def test_function2(self):
        func1_value = 5
        with patch("module2.function1", return_value=func1_value) as patched_func1:
            function2_value = function2()
        assert function2_value == 2*func1_value


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Test result:

```sh
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```